# SQL query not working but works in PHPMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql

I have a web application and I'm trying to modify one of the queries. The query fetches information (from a table named voyage_list) and returns various fields.

I want to modify the query so that it is based on certain filters the user applies (which will be placed in the URL).

I can't get the query to work in the web application, but if I copy the query and execute it directly within PHPMyAdmin, it works fine.

```
$vesselFilter = $_GET['vesselFilter'];
$vesselArray = explode(',', $vesselFilter);

$arrayCount = count($vesselArray);
$sqlExtend = ' status = 1 AND';

foreach ($vesselArray as $value) {
 $i = $i + 1;
 $sqlExtend .= " vesselID = '$value'";

 if ($i < $arrayCount){
  $sqlExtend .= " OR";
 }
}

$newQuery = "SELECT * FROM voyage_list WHERE" . $sqlExtend;
echo $newQuery;

$query = $db->query($newQuery)->fetchAll();
```

I appreciate the above is pretty messy, but it's just so I can try and figure out how to get the query to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: this is **vulnerable** to **sql inhection** so use only  **prepared statements with parameters**

Comment: `$newQuery` comes out as what? `$db` is PDO?

Comment: And what does "not working" mean? 0 rows returned? An exception?

Comment: 0 rows are returned

Comment: Still pending 2 other questions

Comment: $newQuery executes as

SELECT * FROM voyage_list WHERE status = 1 AND vesselID = '8' OR vesselID = '9' OR vesselID = '10' OR vesselID = '16'

Comment: It'd probably be easier to do `WHERE status = 1 AND vesselID in()` and build your integers in there. Still dont know if you are using PDO or mysqli so question still unanswerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That query probably doesn't return what you think it does. `AND` takes precedence over `OR`, so it will return the first vessel in the list if the status is 1, and also any other vessel in the list, regardless of status.

You'd do better to create a query with an `IN` clause like this:

```
SELECT * FROM voyage_list WHERE status = 1 AND vesselID IN(8,9,10)
```

Here's some code to do just that:

```
$vesselFilter = $_GET['vesselFilter'];


// Validate data. Since we're expecting a string containing only integers and commas, reject anything else
// This throws out bad data and also protects against SQL injection.
if (preg_match('/[^0-9,]/', $vesselFilter)) {
    echo "Bad data in input";
    exit;
}

// filter out any empty entries.
$vesselArray = array_filter(explode(',', $vesselFilter));


// Now create the WHERE clause using IN
$sqlExtend = 'status = 1 AND vesselID IN ('.join(',', $vesselArray).')';


$newQuery = "SELECT * FROM voyage_list WHERE " . $sqlExtend;
echo $newQuery;

$query = $db->query($newQuery)->fetchAll();
var_dump($query);
```